# Django form inheritance for CreateView and UpdateView

Tags: django, inheritance, django-forms, formview

I have a CreateView and UpdateView for my model. They are really similar, only `dispatch` differs. I also have a long `form_valid` which should be applied with both, CreateView and UpdateView. How do I write this so there is no duplicity?

I created a mixin like this:

```
class ModelMixin(object):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
```

and then added it to views:

```
class ModelCreateView(ModelMixin, CreateView):
    pass

class ModelUpdateView(ModelMixin, UpdateView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #custom dispatch method for UpdateView
```

But I am not sure about this approach. I doubt I should inherit from `object` in ModelMixin. How to do this inheritance properly?

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing in `dispatch`? It's very rare to need to define that method at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman depending on data in model, I raise Http404 there. Basically only some objects can be updated.

Comment: That should probably happen in `get_object`.

Comment: If you're using python 2.7, always inherit from `object`, in python3 it's implicit. Your solution is good.

Comment: @DanielRoseman hm, ok. Thanks.